# Execute multiple ex commands in bash shell script

Tags: ex

I want to execute 2 ex commands using a shell script. For example: on a file called `test`
Print lines containing `.jsp`.

```
:/.jsp/ p
```

Add * to the beginning of those lines.

```
:s/^/\*/
```

How can I make a shell script that executes them both? I've tried a couple of things,
but the second command is never executed. It only does the first command.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to print using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) and update using [ex](/questions/tagged/ex)

```
sed -n '/jsp/p' test;ex -c 'g/jsp/ s/^/*/' -c 'wq' test
```